# Principal Component giving one component for each variable

Tags: r, pca

I have a total of 50 variables (150 rows of data). Prior to putting the values into prcomp () (in R) I logged the data. When I do prcomp(log.data, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE), I still get 50 PCs for the 50 variables. Why is this the case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because that's how PCA works. Usually you would look at something like the eigenvalues for those PCs to decide which ones to actually keep for your analysis (or which ones are actually useful). Typically people will just keep the first few PCs and drop the rest. General questions about statistical methods are probably better asked at [stats.se]. Questions here benefit from [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data and the code you have tried.

Comment: Great. Thanks! Does this mean that there is a threshold/criteria that should be met for the PCA? Or is it arbitary?